# Cannot run a servlet inside Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have problem running my servlet. When I try to run it , I get HTTP STATUS 404 the requested resource is not available

**I have *test.class* inside *"..Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\test\WEB-INF\classes"***

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class test extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException{

        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        java.util.Date today=new java.util.Date();
        out.println("<html>"+"<body>"+"<BR>"+"<B>"+"<center>"+today
                     +"</center>"+"<body>"+"</html>");
    }

}
```

**My web.xml is insinde WEB-INF, and it looks like**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>test</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/test<url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I've compiled the .java file with:

..ROOT\test\WEB-INF>**javac -classpath "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar" -d classes test.java**

Answer (score 0):

try by giving fully qualified class name in web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>test</servlet-class> <!-- give the fully qualified class name -->
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/test<url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: If by fully qualified class name you mean that I should add the package name .. i've already tried with package , unfortunately it doesn't start again

Comment: @Alexey_M yes i mean the same i.e, package name.

Comment: **I've changed web.xml, <web-app> tag to:**
_<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
      version="3.1"
      metadata-complete="true">_

**... and it ran**

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is your directory structure: `Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\test\WEB-INF\classes`. Special directory `WEB-INF` must be directly under name of application (`ROOT` in your case).

See Oracle [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-1830/abxft/index.html) for more information.

> A special directory under the document root, WEB-INF, contains
>   everything related to the application that is not in the public
>   document tree of the application. No file contained in WEB-INF can be
>   served directly to the client. The contents of WEB-INF include:
>
> /WEB-INF/classes/* - The directory for servlet and other classes.
>
> /WEB-INF/web.xml and /WEB-INF/sun-web.xml - XML-based deployment 
>   descriptors that specify the web application configuration, 
>   including mappings, initialization parameters, and security constraints.

Comment: I've changed the directory to **Tomcat 7.0\webapps\test\WEB-INF\classes  , but it doesn't run again**

Comment: Specify it does not work. How do you test it - what is url? What does it do?